# Apple certifcates and provisioning profiles - when do they expire?

Tags: ios, certificate, profile, provisioning

I have an Apple Enterprise membership and develop apps for In-House distribution.

I don't understand in which cases I need to rebuild my apps because of expired certificates and/or provisioning profiles.

- Do I need to rebuild the App when the distribution certificate expires?
- Do I need to rebuild the App when the provisioning profile expires?
- Does the provisioning profile expire/become invalid when the included certificate expires?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you need to rebuild when the provisioning profile expires depends on how you are distributing your apps.

If you are following best practice and using an MDM to distribute your apps then you can distribute a new provisioning profile when the old one expires.

If you are using some other distribution method (such as a plain web server) then you will need to rebuild your apps when the provisioning profile expires.

Regardless of the distribution method you need to build a new version and update the installed apps when the distribution certificate expires.

If the distribution certificate expires then the app will stop working, even if the provisioning profile is still valid.

You need to update the app with a new version, signed with the new distribution certificate before the old one expires.

[This WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/705/) has a good explanation of the process.